# jekyll mutate html output

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have an existing site using Jekyll with hundreds of existing images and pages. Most of the images are in html files using the `<img>`. I would like to auto add the width and height attribute to the image tags if its not already present. This will easily allow me to hook up a lazy loading image script.

I've looked high and low for a plugin that will do this for me and the only things I can seem to find are liquid tags. Does anyone know of a script/plugin that will do this or something simular?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to add a with and height? I recommend not to add this in the current world of multi devices. You would loose the responsiveness of your images.

Or do you think it makes sense in your case?

For example in this [demo](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/) you can see, why I would't set it and how you can easily lazy load images. If you need an code example for you specific case, please provide some more code ;)

Comment: In some cases the images directly effect the "length" of the page. Regardless of the viewport that the images are viewed there is only one version of it. Lazy loading works in general but there is no way to know the width and height without loading the image